# How do I pass the data to the json response and to view?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have successfully implemented the fetching of data, Am using loop to fetch the data. how do i pass it to collection;

my data now looks like when i try returning from the controller direct to the view:

```
0
    : 
    {id: 17043, clinic: 1, patient: 7932, unique_id: "63f37ee7a2cc3", purpose: null, external_doctor: null,…}
    1
    : 
    {id: 17002, clinic: 1, patient: 7935, unique_id: "63ce299c7383c", purpose: null, external_doctor: null,…}
```

In my controller I have this code which fetches the data from the InsuranceProforma entity and gets the visits_id then uses it to get data from Visits model of corresponding patient:

```
            $proformas = InsuranceProforma::all();
        $visits = [];
        
        foreach ($proformas as $proforma) {
            $visitId = $proforma->visit_id;
            $visit = Visit::findOrFail($visitId);
            $visits[] = $visit;
        }
    
        //$details = InsuranceProformaResource::collection($visits);
    //return $details;
        return $visits;
```

In my InsuranceProformaResource I have this code which converts the response into a Json responce to pass now to the view. But I've commented it out currently in controller:

```
    <?php

namespace Ignite\Finance\Transformers\invoices;


use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class InsuranceProformaResource extends Resource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'proforma_no'=>$this->proforma_no,
            'visit_id' => $this->visit_id,
            'patient_name' => $this->visits->patient->full_name ?? '-',
            'patient_id' => $this->patient,
            'patient_no' => $this->patient_no ?? '-',
            'policy_number' => @$this->policy_number ?? '-',
            "scheme_name" => @$this->scheme_name ?? '-',
            "amount"=>$this->amount,
            'insurance_name' => $this->insurance_name ?? '-',
            'date'=>$this->created_at->format('Y-m-d'),
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I go about it to return data i.e how the patient name is passed?

currently am getting Call to a member function toBase() on array or when i try changing am getting Call to a member function first() on array

Comment: I don't think Laravel supports eager loading with multiple joins, all I can say is you can just do whereIn and map the result back to the `data` like what laravel does behind the scene.

Comment: The idea of using Eloquent ORM is not to manually define the JOINS yourself, but to define relationships and get data from them. Read how [relationships work](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships) and try to implement them 100%. Do not use joins, that is for a very specific case and you definitely do not need that here. Use relationships and if you still have doubts or issues, edit the question and we will help you

Comment: editted it @matiaslauriti

Answer (score 0):

Eager loading is a mechanism of fetching data from two or more laravel models using joins. This technique is used to solve N+1 query problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel we can send response in JSON format to view using return json() function.
Such as return Response::json(View('user.home')->with('var', $val)->render());
Where $val may be an array or object. User is the folder name in view directory and home is the blade view from which we can easily get value using $var variable.